# Error parsing JSON file in python 3.4

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to load a Json file from a url and parse it on Python3.4 but i get a few errors and I've no idea what they are pointing to. I did verify the json file on the url from jsonlint.com and the file seems fine. The **data.read()** is returning 'byte' file and i've type casted it. The code is

```
import urllib.request
import json

inp = input("enter url :")
if len(inp)<1: inp ='http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json'

data=urllib.request.urlopen(inp)
data_str = str(data.read())

print(type(data_str))

parse_data = json.loads(data_str)

print(type(parse_data))
```

The error that i'm getting is:[image]

Comment: I got the answer, the code shouldn't have been type cast but instead following code had to be used:`data_str = data.read().decode("utf-8")`... I would appreciate it if someone would explaing why the typecast didn't work. Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `str(data.read())` doesn't "cast" your bytes into a string, it just produces a string *representation* of them. This can be seen if you print `data_str`: it's a `str` beginning with `b'`.

To actually decode the JSON, you need to do `data_str = data.read().decode('utf=8')`